# Codeigniter - Format dropdown from query date/datetime

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am fairly new to codeigniter and MVC design. I am converting an old coldfusion MX site to a new design/layout.

Currently I need to propagate a dropdown from a query. The dropdown will be datetime, but I want it to display date only.

DROPDOWN:
2017-10-24 -> 2016-10-24 00:00:00.000

Model:

```
<?php
class Client_model extends CI_Model {
        function __construct(){
                parent::__construct();
        }

        function get_dates($datadate) {
            $project_number = $this->session->userdata ('user_details')[0]->project_number;
            $datadate = array();
                        $this->db->distinct();
                        $this->db->select('datadate');
                        $this->db->where('clientnumber', $project_number);
                        $this->db->group_by("datadate");
                        $this->db->order_by('datadate', 'DESC');
                        $query = $this->db->get('clientdata');

            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
                        $datadate[] = $row;
                }
            }
            log_message('debug',print_r($datadate,TRUE));
            return $datadate;
       }
}
```

Controller:

```
<?php defined("BASEPATH") OR exit("No direct script access allowed");

class client extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function index(){
    $this->load->view("include/header");
    $this->load->model("Client_model");
    $data['datadate'] = $this->Client_model->get_dates($datadate);

    $this->load->view('index', $data);
    $this->load->view("include/footer");
  }
}
?>
```

View:

```
<!-- page content -->
 <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper settingPage">
    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
      <!-- Default box -->
      <div class="box box-success">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
          <h3 class="box-title">Select date/unit</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 aboutshift">

                <?php echo form_dropdown('date',$datadate);?>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.box-body -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.box -->
  </section>
  <!-- /.content -->
</div>
<!-- /.content-wrapper -->
```

[Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfNhi.png)

Debug for array. Need to change the (0, 1, 2, etc) to the date

```
DEBUG - 2017-10-24 11:32:16 --> Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [datadate] => 2016-10-17 00:00:00.000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [datadate] => 2016-10-16 00:00:00.000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [datadate] => 2016-10-15 00:00:00.000
        )
)
```

Comment: jus change from `$this->db->select('datadate');` to `$this->db->select('DATE(datadate)');` to convert datetime to date

Comment: This worked to adjust the format however the drop down still looks like the original picture where I see:

`0
   2017-10-24
1
   2017-10-23
2
   2017-10-24`

How do I get the array identifier to no longer be there, so it just shows:

`2017-10-24
2017-10-23
2017-10-22`

Comment: for that, you need to create the array like this
`$options = array(
        'value'         => 'lable',
        '2016-10-15'           => '2016-10-15',
);`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the date() function in combination with the strtotime() function.

Something similar to

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime($datadate))
```

Or you can do it in the SQL as  PrAtik Lochawala.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function get_dates()
{
    $project_number = $this->session->userdata('user_details')[0]->project_number;
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select('DATE(datadate)');
    $this->db->where('clientnumber', $project_number);
    $this->db->group_by("datadate");
    $this->db->order_by('datadate', 'DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get('clientdata');
    $datadate = $query->result_array();

    return $datadate;
}
```